# RelaxNG choice and regular expression

Tags: relaxng

I have a RelaxNG based XML instance which should allow (choice) `align="right"`, `align="left"` and `align="{ anything here }"`. The right/left is easy:

```
 attribute name="align">
   <a:documentation>doc for attrib</a:documentation>
   <choice>
      <value>left</value>
      <a:documentation>doc for left</a:documentation>
      <value>right</value>
      <a:documentation>doc for right</a:documentation>
   </choice>
</attribute>
```

But how can I allow the user to enter `{ ... }` as an alternative to the two values above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the XML Schema `string` type and set a `pattern` on it. Here's an example:

```
<grammar xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
         datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
  <start>
    <element name="top">
      <oneOrMore>
        <element name="foo">
          <attribute name="align">
            <choice>
              <value>left</value>
              <value>right</value>
              <data type="string">
                <param name="pattern">\{.+\}</param>
              </data>
            </choice>
          </attribute>
        </element>
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>
</grammar>
```

And a test file:

```
<top>
  <!-- valid cases -->
  <foo align="{fasf}"></foo>
  <foo align="left"></foo>
  <foo align="right"></foo>
  <!-- invalid cases -->
  <foo align="fasf"></foo>
  <foo align="{}"></foo>
  <foo align="a{c}b"></foo>
</top>
```

Note the comments that delimit valid and invalid cases.

The regular expression I used allows things like `align="{ab{c}d}"`. Curly braces are valid inside the curly braces that start and end the attribute value. I've not see any reason to disallow it.